# Jenkins plugin for finding not responding application

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am testing software with some application/tool software using Jenkins. Sometimes the application does not respond or it gets hanged.

Manual workaround is to kill application process and restart it (power off and on).

Does anyone know that is there any Jenkins plugin which can track application process whether it is working or hanging?

I am using job time out approach but it is time-consuming to wait.

Comment: I would need more detail than `testing software with some application/tool software using Jenkins` to help you. Is your Jenkins job hanging, or are you trying to use Jenkins to monitor another application? It's unclear.

Comment: Usually, I'd say you configure a timeout for the job/step.

Comment: @DanWilson Jenkins job is not hanging it works fine. I have configured Jenkins job to automate the testing. I have written batch script in Jenkins job option 'Execute Windows batch command' to call application which I use for testing. It is similar as you have mentioned monitoring another application using Jenkins.